# Form needs to handle two submit buttons in PHP

Tags: php, forms

In my HTML I have a form where users can register or login.The problem is both Register and Login buttons are in the same form, and they are handled by two scripts: register.php and login.php.

In

```
<form action=" ">
```

there could just be one script name. So how to make the form able to handle two submit buttons(two scripts)?

```
  <form action="register.php" method="post" class="login_form">     

    <div class="login_form_input_container">   
      <label for="email" class="login_form_label">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="login_form_input">
    </div>

    <div class="login_form_input_container">  
      <label for="password" class="login_form_label">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="login_form_input">
    </div>

    <a href="forgot_password/" class="forgot_password_link">Forgot password?</a>

    <input type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login_submit" value="Log In" class="login_form_submit">

    <input type="submit" id="register_submit" name="register_submit" value="Register" class="login_form_submit">

  </form>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['btn_name']))`

Comment: Why do you need one script to handle both?

Comment: @Blender No he wants a form that can submit to varying scripts.

Comment: @TwilightSun: Then you use two forms.

Comment: @Blender Are you reading his question? He doesn't want to make two forms.

Comment: @TwilightSun: I want to make my entire website's background to flash random colors. You can surely do it, but is it a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another script `register_or_login.php`, let that script handle the form submission and make it route to either the login or register backend script:

```
if (isset($_POST['login_submit'])) {
    require 'login.php';
} elseif (isset($_POST['register_submit'])) {
    require 'register.php';
}
```

A button is not much different from, say, a checkbox or textfield; if you give it a name it will be present in `$_POST`.

Comment: Jack, I got your point. In your code, can I just use Header(Location: login.php) to redirect the user, instead of using require('login.php')? Which is better?

Comment: @user3205002 The POST data is not retained when you do a header redirect.

Comment: Jack, I see, if using header() redirect, then the $_POST data cannot be transferred between scripts, unless other data transfer methods like SESSION is used. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user3205002 I suppose; something would have to intercept the POST data, store it in a (temporary) location and then perform the redirect; this seems like overcomplicating the problem though.

Comment: Jack, thanks, your way is simple and effective. So in this register_or_login.php, there could just be your if..elseif... conditional, nothing else, and then ends the script, right? I will code anything else needed in register.php and login.php themselves(like page header and footer, etc.)

Comment: @user3205002 Yeah, that's the idea; the script contains only that.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check with [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) which one was sent/clicked like so

```
if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){
    //do login
}elseif(isset($_POST['register_submit'])){
    //do register
}
```

I just thought of this and checked that if a user just hits enter without clicking a submit button it sends the first submit name/value as a default. So in your case `login_submit` will be sent if user just hits enter which is probably a good thing.

Comment: make the action wherever your php script is